# Unable to send messages using AMQP with Spring boot JmsTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, amqp, spring-amqp, jmstemplate

I'm trying to send messages using the JmsTemplate of Spring boot.
I configure everything using the autoconfiguration through properties.
These are the properties I set :

- spring.activemq.broker-url
- spring.activemq.user
- spring.activemq.password

I have been able to get this working as desired when I configure the broker-url to tcp://localhost:61616, but whenever I change it to amqp://localhost:5672, I get the error : 
Failed to connect to [amqp://localhost:5672] after: 10 attempt(s) continuing to retry.

For a project I'm working on, I should be using AMQP.

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you running the broker externally? You need to enable the AMQP transport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot's support for activemq is JMS only.

Spring does not have support for AMQP 1.0 at all; only 0.9.1 with RabbitMQ.